# synchronize audio and video using frame timestamps

Tags: python, audio, video, synchronization

I'm writing a multi-threaded application in python 3, one thread grab frames from a webcam using opencv, another one record audio frames using pyaudio. Both threads put the frames in a separate circular buffer, with absolute timestamp for every frame.
Now I'd like to create another thread who read from the buffers and join audio and video frame together using the timestamp information, then save everything to a mp4 file. The only thing I found is merging audio and video files using for example ffmpeg, but nothing related to frames on the fly.
Do I really need to create the audio and video files before join them? What I don't understand in this case is how to handle synchronization..
Any hints will be appreciated.

EDIT

In reponse to the comments, the timestamps are created by me and are absolute, I use a data structure which contains the actual data (video or audio frame) and the timestamp. The point is that audio is recorded with a microphone and video using a webcam, which are different hardware, not synchronized.

Webcam grab a frame, elaborate it and put in a circular buffer using my data structure (data + timestamp).

Microphone record an audio frame, elaborate it and put in a circular buffer using my data structure (data + timestamp).

So I have 2 buffers, I want to pop frames and join together in whatever video file format, matching the timestamps in the most accurate way possible. My idea is something that can add an audio frame to a video frame (I will check about timestamps matching).

Comment: Using your third Thead, you could try send the a/v data (bytes) to FFmpeg using **stdout**. See [**this tutorial**](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/). FFmpeg is clever enough to synchronize by itself. You tell it (or set) the output must be 30 FPS and it will await 30 frames (or bitmaps, if using that) and also any sound bytes it gets will be added to video.

Comment: PS: I don't use Python or OpenCV so... what **video** format do you have when you record _"video with OpenCV"_? Aternatively, Is taking raw bitmap screenshots from webcam as frames an acceptable option to you (meaning no video codec, just RGB pixel data)? Are you creating the timestamps yourself or you meant the stamps as made by the audio / video codecs themselves?

Comment: Edited, please take a loot and tell me if something is not clear

Comment: That depends on the encoder you are using which you did not specify. As VCone says, e.g. when using ffmpeg and stdin piping, it will process the frames in the order they come in, so the synchronisation is up to your own code.